# Fetch content of older version of excel files from SharePoint document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, version, history

I have a list of folders in SharePoint document library and each folder contains an excel file. Now I have to fetch the content (using Powershell?) of last all versions of that excel file. Any idea?

Comment: Do you already have a sample bit of code that you're using that isn't working?  [Normally](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we would want to see what, specific, issues you are having, as opposed to writing it for you from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing files in SharePoint library without SharePoint module via Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157102/listing-files-in-sharepoint-library-without-sharepoint-module-via-powershell)